# Compile SWC with references to classes not included

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop, swc

I'm trying to compile an SWC with a few classes as an extension to a framework, it complains that Signals and my View class cant be found. They aren't in the project as any project this would be used on would already have the framework SWC included containing these classes.

Is there anyway to tell it not to cry over missing classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No if you reference any class then it has to be present.

What you can do is making those classes implement an interface(s) and have that interface(s) referenced in your swc.

Comment: ahh that sucks, ok, ill just package it up with the rest of the framework, I just wanted to have some sort of component model going on for future development but sticking it all together isn't too bad I suppose